# Arrays from a different file in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to read a 2D array from a certain file. I've got the code so it tells me how many arrays there are in the file, but my problem is I'm not sure how to finish the for statement. This is what I have so far....

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project2 {

/*Main Method*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("prog2.txt"));
  int number = 0;
  while (sc.hasNext()) {
    sc.next();
    number++;
  }
  System.out.println(number);


  /*int [][] hours = {
  {2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8},
  {7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4},
  {3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2},
  {9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1},
  {3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8},
  {3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4},
  {3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4},
  {6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9},
};*/

for (int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
  int sum = totalHours(hours, i);
  System.out.println("Employee " + i + ": " + sum);
  }
}

public static int totalHours(int[][] time, int rowIndex) {
  int total = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for (int column = 0; column < time[i].length; column++) {
    total += time[rowIndex][column];
  }
  return total;
  }
}
```

The int[][] hours was example given in the book. The for statement is setup for those values. I'm trying to get the values from a certain file(the values are unknown) to work with this for statement. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please specify how the data is stored in the file ? (one value per line OR one row per line etc. etc.)

Comment: We definitely need to know more about how the file is set up.  Right now, it looks like you're assuming that it's just a bunch of numbers, and you are figuring out how many numbers there are in the file--but if it's a 2D array, you can't tell how many rows and how many columns there are, just by counting how many numbers there are in the file.  There has to be some other structure to the file.

Comment: Your code looks fine so far. Continue and try reading the file and construct the 2d array. If you  run into any *specific* issue - post it here.

Comment: I wasn't told what the file would be. Just that it would be a 2D array. I know that it will be Int's but that's all. I see how the commented out array looks but that was in the book. I don't know what's going to be on the file.

Comment: this is what I'm told......... Suppose the weekly hours for all employees are stored in a 2D array. Each row records an employee's seven day work hours with seven columns. Write a program that displays employees and their total hours in decreasing order of total hours from a file. Also read the number of employees first.

Comment: OK, it looks like the *first* number that you scan from the file is going to be the number of employees.  The phrase "from a file" seems pretty disconnected, though--it doesn't seem to give enough info.  Assuming this is homework, I think you need to go back and ask your teacher for more info about what the file looks like.  That's what I would do, since I can't figure out what the assignment means.

Comment: Are you in the same class as the person who asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749388/loading-a-2d-array-from-a-file)?

Comment: It seems to be the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
column < time[i].length
```

`i` should be `rowIndex`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your rows and columns this way:

```
for (int row = 0; row < hours.length; row++) {

int total = 0;

  for (int column = 0; column < hours[raw].length; column++) {

      total += hours[row][column];
  }

system.out.println("Row total: " + total);
```

}